# jQuery Ajax Call to WebService returns “No Transport” error in IE8 - NO CROSS-DOMAIN

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

This question may seems like has been asked already, but not in this partular case.

I have my application that run like this:

```
http://localhost:51198/Home/Subpage?type=1
```

and my webservice is called like this:

```
http://localhost:2880/DetailsService.svc/GetVisitors
```

So it is NOT cross domain.

It works perfectly in IE9+ but when I'm on IE8 it gives "No Transport Error".

Check this other question as a reference for any code as Iøm doing everything exactly like there, apart from the corss-domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And here is the answer. :)

Remember to always add:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

before at the beginning of your code. Be careful this has to happen before any ajax call.

And this is **needed** also when the call is **NOT cross-domain** in **IE8**